# Can we disable creating yammer group by end users

Tags: office-365, yammer

With yammer activation, everyone in the network can get an option to create Yammer group both Internal and external.

with a little research - I got steps to disable external groups creation, although want to know if internal group creation can be controlled with in Yammer

Please provide steps/PowerShell script to do so

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, By Yammer design there is no option to stop Yammer users from creating their own groups.

However, the Admin can monitor/delete the groups created by different users in `Private Mode` as the following:

- Navigate to Network Admin > Content Mode > Private content mode.

For more details check

- [How to prevent users to create groups by themselves?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_yammer-mso_o365brs/how-to-prevent-users-to-create-groups-by/98e7be4f-f717-4d47-a223-a994154bcf7c)
- [Disabling end-user creation of Yammer Groups](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_yammer-mso_o365app/disabling-end-user-creation-of-yammer-groups/629e00e1-5d49-48c5-ae42-376d5bf4fe5b)